# In Dungeons of Dredmor, what determines the result when offering items to Krong?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

When you put an item on the altar of Krong, the outcome seems pretty random: either it gets cursed or some benefits (sometimes these are not very relevant - as in an armor item getting pluses or minuses to mana regeneration when playing a warrior).

Is this process random, or is there anything you can do to influence the outcome? I've had a couple of theories:

1. If you've bought the item from a shop, it's more likely to be cursed
2. If you've crafted the item yourself, it's more likely to get a good effect
3. If Krong has blessed an item before, he won't do so again
4. It's completely random, the game chooses one 'stat' to modify and does so in a random direction (most likely +/- 1)

Only theory #4 seems to be holding up so far... I've never seen a curse and a blessing at the same time.

So how does Krong work, exactly?

Comment: I can confirm that Krong **will** bless an item twice. I had a _very_ fancy fedora for a while.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Krong is completely random. However, if an artifact is already an artifact, he is more likely to try to increment an existing statistic as opposed to giving you a new one.

Comment: Increment, or decrement? Anyway, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Gaslamp Games here on Gaming.SE, w00t! You guys have developed a damned fun game.

Answer (score 0):

5/7 chance to give 1 or 2 positive effects. 2/7 chance to give 1 or 2 negative effects.